Integrate STM32f103 with zubax gnss module to receive data over uavcan
I want to receive data from zubax gnss v2.4 module to stm32f103 board using CAN protocol over uavcan libraries. Im using HAL libraries in stmcubeide. Configured CAN in stm32 and not receiving data from zubax,using 1mbps and 500kbps baudrate for CAN, I need inputs to achieve this.
Tried receiving data over CAN but not receiving anything from zubax module

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
